# Stripe error in Express/React: You did not set a publishable key

Tags: reactjs, express, key, stripe-payments

I'm able to run my Express/React app locally without Stripe errors, paying successfully in test mode, but when on Heroku, I get this error on button click: `You did not set a valid publishable key. Call Stripe.setStripePublishableKey() with your publishable key.` Here is my setup:

in heroku, I have my keys added there as config vars

in **config/dev.js** I have all keys set as strings

in **config/prod.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  googleClientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  googleClientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  cookieKey: process.env.COOKIE_KEY,
  stripePublishableKey: process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
  stripeSecretKey: process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
};
```

in **client/src/components/Payments.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class Payments extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <StripeCheckout 
        name="Emaily"
        description="Add $5 for 5 email credits"
        amount={ 500 }
        token={ token => this.props.handleToken(token) }
        stripeKey={ process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY }
      >
      <button className="btn">
      Add Credits
      </button>
      </StripeCheckout>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(Payments);
```

Create React App requires I use REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY rather than stripePublishableKey or STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY, and I've tried changing it my env variables instead to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: If you log out `process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY` does it have a value, is it set as a config var in Heroku? `stripeKey` here should definitely be your publishable key, if you swap in `process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` does it work as you expect?

Comment: @duck Yes, logging out `process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY` outputs my publishable key.

Comment: @duck Yes, logging out `process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY` outputs my publishable key.  The config var for this publishable key in heroku is STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY and is the same one logged with `process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY`.  When I swapped out REACT_APP_STRIPE... here for STRIPE... and pushed to heroku it didnt fix the prob.

Comment: Here is the log from my heroku  as I go through the process: `checkout.js:2 StripeCheckout.configure: Type mismatch for option 'key':
Looking for type 'string', but instead we found 'undefined'.
You can learn about the available configuration options in the Checkout docs:
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout`

Comment: UPDATE: I found the problem: It was because I'd named it REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY where I was instructed to by create react app in the JSX but not in the keys files AND on heroku. I just changed all to process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY and it works on heroku now

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue until I removed my .env.production from my .gitignore file. According to the React Docs:
   [Env Links and CRA](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

> .env files should be checked into source control (with the exclusion of .env*.local).

I realized that my dev environment was running correctly since the .env.development and .env.production files were being compiled by CRA into the bundle.js. If you have these in your .gitignore, heroku won't be able to find them. Hope this helps!